# Use Dynamically Inheritance C#

Tags: c#, inheritance

In my project I am using .CSHTML page and .aspx page .. So I have two abstract classed like

```
public abstract class RazorAbstractPage : System.Web.WebPages.WebPage
public abstract class AbstractPage : System.Web.UI.Page
```

Both are using the same code in it .. So there is duplicate code in the page ... Is there any way to Inherit on condition based like for Razor System.Web.WebPages.WebPage and otherwise System.Web.WebPages.WebPage , something like this ..

Your suggestions will be much appreciable .

Comment: If they're the same, why not just remove one and replace it with the other?  Why bother with this conditional inheritance *at all*?

Comment: No, you can't do that. If you have shared code though, consider refactoring it out into a class of its own that is injected into your derived classes.

Comment: Extract the common code to a separate class. The parent types are *very* different, so having the same code doesn't mean there's *any* inheritance relation between those two

Comment: why not stick to cshtml or aspx and then you only have one of those to deal with

Comment: Inheritance means there's an `is-a` relation. It's not a good code reuse mechanism.

Comment: There is the concept of "[Composition over Inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)". This is the perfect place to follow it.

Comment: @Amy the difference is with the different inherited class

Comment: @AndreiDragotoniu could u please be more specific ?

Comment: @Devdotnet Then it isn't conditional, is it?

Comment: @Amy any condition we can add for inheriting like
if razor then class a will be inherited else b

Answer (score 0):

No. C# is a statically typed language. All inheriting must be done ahead of time. There is "dynamic", but as far as I know that does not allow declaring types this way.

The way I would approach this is to make a wrappers around System.Web.WebPages.WebPage and System.Web.UI.Page that have a common interface, and put your code in a third class that take a object with this interface in the constructor. I.e. [use composition instead of inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance).